# how to create series number for that actually sequence for website form in php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, dreamweaver

I am a beginner to build website system for my project. How to create ascending series number that actually a primary key for my table in database?

So when the user want to input the data, there is already have a number series in that form. so it will be easy for me to check their data only based on the form's series number. so can you help me with some tutorial and coding?

I am using XAMPP control panel and Dreamweaver cs6.

Comment: set Auto Increment + Primary Key for that id in DB

Comment: i know, but the user still have to input the data for that id. i don't want they input the data for that id. i want that id already filled automatically , so they only have to input others data. is that possible ?

Comment: Dude, you want auto increment unique key for each user right ?

Comment: probably. i wish you understand what i mean. is that possible ?

Comment: The user doesn't need to know this information

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table. Very often we would like the value of the primary key field to be created automatically every time a new record is inserted. MySQL uses the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)**

Answer (score 0):

While creating your database table use following syntax:

CREATE TABLE table_name (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 DATA_TYPE, col3 DATA_TYPE,......)

On your php query code you can fetch the primary key generated by table by following mysql method

LAST_INSERT_ID()

which return the last row ID inserted into the database table